# How do I add an extra condition to select statement?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I would like to add an extra condition in my select statement. This condition is to check if RemovedReason Word has a string value. Sometimes there may be an  empty string so I need to check the string has something in it.

**Sample Xml document**

```
<Test ID="ABCDEF">
    <Type Op="A" Word="JXM">
        <DateAdded Op="A">04/27/2017</DateAdded>
        <RemovedDate Op="A"/>
        <RemovedReason Op="A" Word="Removed for Testing only"/>
        <Comment Op="A"/>
    </Type>
</Test>
```

**xslt sample code not working**

```
<xsl:value-of select="(count(//[((Test/@Word='JXM') or (Test/@Word='REP') or (Test/@Word='JAM')) and string-length(Connection/RemovedReason/@Word) > 0]))"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<xsl:value-of select="count(//Test[Type/@Word='JXM' and normalize-space(Type/RemovedReason/@Word)])"/>` should do.

Comment: Thanks Honnen. What if my condition is checking for say 3 different Type/@Word e.g JXM, RPE, APE etc using or between them and then finally add the condition to check for ReasonRemoved. How do I do that?

Comment: Well, as you have tagged the question as [tag:xslt-2.0] you can simply use the expression `Type/@Word=('JXM', 'RPE', 'APE')` for the comparison. Or use an `or`, if you really don't know how to do that then try an XPath tutorial.

Comment: I did figure it out. Thanks for your help.